# Setting content of an Ext.container.Container from a file

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TopToolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.toptoolbar',
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.applyIf(this, {
            layout: 'fit',
            cls : 'x-bottombar',
            html : 'HTML FRAGMENT'
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Originally this component had contained a small fragment of html but now its going to be significantly increased. So I'd like to move it to an external file but I found no way in the docs to do this. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have a big chunk of html in my js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `loader` configuration on the component:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-loader

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader

Comment: Thanks those links really helped. I replaced the html component with `loader: {url: 'external.html',autoLoad: true}`